# Anaconda install new packages without updating conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install a python package by using `conda install`. It pops this message and halt:

[image]

Does it mean I have to update conda first? Is it possible to install new packages without updating to the latest version?

Comment: _It pops this message and halt:_ It interrupts the operation? As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer from the [Anaconda GitHub](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1094), one can achieve what you are looking for through `conda install <package> conda=X.X` where X.X is your conda version.

Additionally, one can suppress the conda auto-update through the following command `conda config --set auto_update_conda false`

Answer (score 0):

It is preferred to have latest Conda version to install packages.Updating Conda is easy.  The terminal also shows you the respective command for this.
You can find more help here: [Conda update](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/update.html)